# Resize $mdSidenav With Any Event

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to resize [$mdSidenav](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdSidenav) with any event:

```
<md-button ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
  Open Left Menu
</md-button>
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2"
                    md-component-id="left"
                    md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
</md-sidenav>
```

and js:

```
$scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
    var el = $element.find('md-sidenav');
    el.toggleClass("hover");
};
```

With this approach, class could added, but has no effect on size of [md-sidenav](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdSidenav)
I don't know if this is the right approach to resize the md-sidenav. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
md-sidenav.hover {
     min-width: 20px;
     max-width: 20px
}
```

Comment: what styles are you adding in hover class?

Comment: md-sidenav.hover {
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 20px
}

Answer (score 0):

```
.md-sidenav-left.hover {
     min-width: 20px;
     max-width: 20px
}
```